# Spring Rest 415 Unsupported Types Error

Tags: spring, rest

We are in the process of changing all our web services from GET to POST. After the change to RequestMethod.Post I am getting 415 Unsupported Operations. The URL's to the service are like this. /WebService. So no extension. The way the services are being done these services are only working with JSON. I am unsure how to configure the content negotiating resolver without breaking the mediaTypes. Is that the problem or is it something else?

The other thing I attempted to do was change the @RequestBody to just accept a String. In that case at least it hit the web service. But when I change it to an object or something of that nature, it's the 415 Unsupported Error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to send up objects to your Web Method are the objects serilizable? If not I believe they must be, this is why sending up a string is working fine. In some cases some classes may contain List or other types that are not initially serilizable but anything can be essentially if you write the code for it

Comment: I think you may be correct. I am using restclient to test currently but it is to be consumed by another client. How does one ensure that the object is serialized?